# PDO freebsd couldn't find driver

Tags: php, mysql, freebsd

I'm trying to connect on my database on Freebsd, php 56 using this code:

```
<?php
$host = "x";
$user  = "x";
$password =  "x";

try {
    $account = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=account", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e);
}

try {
    $player = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=player", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e);
}
```

and I'm getting this error

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/config/db.php:7 
Stack trace: 
#0 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/config/db.php(7): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=x', 'x', 'x') 
#1 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/index.php(3): include('/usr/local/www/...') 
#2 {main}
```

so I get that I should install the drivers.
I didn't find anything useful on google for freebsd. Can you help me?

Comment: Check is you have enabled `extension=php_pdo_mysql.so` in php.ini

Comment: Is databases/php56-pdo_mysql installed?

Comment: @bato3 I'm working on freebsd.

Comment: @julp no, and that's what I'm asking for - commands for installing it

Comment: How did you install php in the first place? With packages? (`pkg install php56-pdo_mysql`) With ports? (`make -C /usr/ports/databases/php56-pdo_mysql install`) [Don't forget to read FreeBSD's handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)

Comment: I didn't. Php was already installed by another person. I don't know. Should I install it again?

Comment: I installed with make -C /usr/ports/databases/php56-pdo_mysql install and it's working. ty.